# Ambari agent cannot reach ambari server

Tags: ambari

I'm trying to use Ambari.

First, because I cannot use the root permission of lab's server, I tried to start Ambari agent manually.

This is my conf of agent:
[image: Ambari agent conf]

The server port is 8082, but I got this error in agent log:

> ```
> server at http://172.19.104.24:8082 is not reachable.
> ```

Before that, I closed the SELinux of server, and added rules in server's iptables. So I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Have you turned the iptables off? Did you edit the network configuration file (etc/sysconfig/network)? Also try running setenforce 0.